# How to see mouse current position in nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, browser-automation, nightwatch.js

I am pretty new in nightwatch.js and i want to check current position of my mouse, is there any way to see the mouse current position ? currently i am using

```
client.getLocation("#myId", function (result) {
  console.log(result.x);
  console.log(result.x);
});
```

but above code giving the location of the #myId element, if i use following code.

```
client.moveToElement("#myId", 250, 70, function (result) {
  console.log(result.status);
});
```

**After execution** of the above function my cursor will move from 250 pixels into x axis and 70 pixels to y axis from #myid element.

But how i can detect **previous position** of my mouse ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the location of the element that you moved it to. In Python and Chrome, the mouse starts in the middle of the window, also after resizing.